# How to modify wordpress/woocommerce php code to not apply to single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code in my functions.php file -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );
 
function price_prefix_suffix( $price, $product ){
    $price = '<span class="price-thin">From</span> ' . $price . '';
 return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );  
}
```

I would like to change this code so it DOES NOT apply to single product pages.  I only want this to apply to the home page, product category pages, but it is causing a problem when it appears on the single product page.

I am trying to add if(!is_product) to do this but I'm not sure where to put the if clause. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if clause inside the function,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );
function price_prefix_suffix( $price, $product ){
    if( !is_product() ){
        $price = '<span class="price-thin">From</span> ' . $price . '';
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );  
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks.. it works but it doesn't fix the problem I was trying to solve, that the minimum price loads for a second before updating to selected variation price. Do you know how I might fix this. Thanks. Please see here - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/romantic-red-roses/?attribute_pa_stem-size=30

Comment: @Michelle Could you please clarify ? I didn't get your problem exactly. On checking the URL i didn't find any loading issues when changing variation price.

Comment: if you look at the URL i sent, the big price at the top of the variations says R250 for a second when it loads, then changes to R520. I'm trying to stop the lowest price from loading for a second first. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Got it. It needs a detailed check. I cannot give you a proper solution without checking the site. You can deactivate plugins other than WooCommerce and also switch theme to storefront ( if you are using another theme ) to see if problem persists

Comment: @Michelle This can be due to many reasons. Code optimization can fix this if that's the case. What i said is a general procedure to rule out plugin compatibility issues.

Comment: @Michelle Please mark it as answer since the answer solves your question.